# Auto-post to Facebook when a channel entry is published

Tags: add-on, channel-entries

We would like to set something up so that when we publish a new article (channel entry) to our site it also creates a post on our Facebook page. What solutions are people using for this? I found [the Social Update add-on on devot:ee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/social-update), are you using this, a different add-on, or some other method?

Comment: Adam, did any of the answers help you? If yes, please mark the answer correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm personally using [RSS Graffiti](http://www.rssgraffiti.com/) on Facebook to parse in my RSS feed and post it as Facebook entries.  Has worked brilliantly and was dead simple to set up.

-Lisa

Answer (score 3):

I know that [Social Login Pro](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/social-login-pro) allows you to do this among many other features the only thing I think that might be a problem for you that it would want to post the article to the Authors Facebook page instead of a page for the entire site as it requires the user links their Facebook account to their EE member account.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using http://twitterfeed.com/.

Easy setup, stable service. Free.
Twitterfeed uses an RSS feed to post to FaceBook, Twitter and LinkedIn.